# How to send messages to a specific channel inside a telegram supergroup using a telegram bot?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf.js

So i have a group with two channels. I want the bot to send the messages to a specific one, but it just sends all messages to the general channel grom the group. I understand that the id changes but even using getChat method I dont get the specific id for the channel. Is there a way to do this?

I've tried running
 `bot.on("text", (ctx) => { bot.telegram.sendMessage("11111111", "hi"); });`

and expected the message to be sent to the channel i wanted to, but it just sends it to the general chat of the group.

I've also tried this:
`
bot.command("info", async (ctx) => {

const chatId = ctx.chat.id;
const chatInfo = await ctx.telegram.getChat(chatId);

ctx.reply(`Información del chat:\n${JSON.stringify(chatInfo, null, 2)}`);
});`

but the id is that of the group and not the one from the channel.